# Office is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm developeing an outlook add-in, and I'm trying to use Office.js. From my understanding, it is automatically injected. However, when I do something like this:

```js
angular.module(APP).controller('ExtensionController', [
    '$scope',
    'apiService',
    'authService',
    'msService',
    function ($scope, apiService, authService, msService) {

        console.log('TEST: ', Office);

        
        $scope.loggedIn = false;
```

I get Office is not defined.

I'm assuming Office is not loaded yet. How do I solve this problem? I'm a bit of a newbie in this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you included `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your `<head>` tag, per the instructions [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office.md)?

Comment: Also, note that office APIs are only available after Office.initialize (defined by your code) is called.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office (Initializing your add-in section) You should wait until then before executing logic that requires office API.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the Office.js tag in the head of the html up more toward the top.
Its like your script is initializing before the Office.js is.

Just like if you were to say put Bootstrap.js before the jquery.js in the head Bootstrap would say jQuery is not defined because bootstrap is dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are bootstrapping the Angular app *inside the function that you assign to Office.initialize*. For details, see this help document: [Develop Add-ins with Angular2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2)